# Is it possible and how to set the cursor in pygame? (Python)

Tags: python, pygame, cursor

Is it possible and how do I set my own cursor in Python using pygame modules?

The point is, I wrote a pygame (python) game and would like to change the cursor to my own, which I painted myself in RealWordCursorEditor.

I know there is a "set_cursor" function and I don't know if I can set my own cursor with it?

If so, how, but if it can't be pygame, can it be pure Python or some other module?

Please help!

Comment: You will probably need to hide the mouse cursor then draw your custom image at the cursor location.

Comment: This is a very good idea! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [HERE](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html), these are the docs for setting the mouse cursor using pygame.